# can an O2 sensor be leaking itself? when holding my fingers around the sensor where the wiring starts, it felt like exhaust came up from the housing

Tags: o2-sensor

leaking O2 sensor
l fixed an exhaust leak on the “ribs” on the manifold on my 2006 chrysler 300 crd 3.0 td
when checking if the problem was solved l could still smell the exhaust and when holding my fingers loose around the top of the sensor housing where the wiring starts, it felt like the exhaust came out of the housing..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.

Everything in your car can break apart, broken, worn, and damaged.

Even for new parts sometimes you will get a defective item.

For leaking parts, you can check with bubble:

- Use water + detergent (this should be enough for making bubble)
- splash or spray the suspected area or
- use a sponge, dip the sponge into the detergent solution, and use the
  sponge to check.

[Source](https://www.cavagnagroup.com/checking-for-a-gas-leak-on-your-propane-cylinder/)

Edit:

Additional information on HOW to spray it or use the sponge for the O2 sensor housing:

- Do not spray it after the engine hot (after running around etc)
- Spray it when the engine is on first turns on / cold start. (meaning when the engine is cool, not cold - cold obviously your engine wouldn't start)
- Use extra precaution to check if **glowing red** then it's not good
- Use extra precaution
- Do not spray it too much

Another one using vac shop to blow from the exhaust to check without turn on the engine:
[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtkXZDaevKQ) (i do not recommend this way)

Comment: As this gets to exhaust temperature, will it evaporate before any bubbles get to be seen? Or will the steam hide what you expect to see?

Comment: exhaust temperature outside especially in O2 sensor housing will not evaporate everything out from the sponge even the spray could attach awhile..furthermore if you try it in the morning or not after a long drive.. did you never try it in your life as a mechanic?

Comment: I’ve seen exhaust manifolds glowing red... last thing you want is to spray cold fluid on a hot CI manifold.

Comment: Did i say hot? did I said waiting to glowing red and then spray it?

Comment: BTW, not had a life as a mechanic, but an auto-electrician... now mechanical engineer: powerplant analysis and thermofluids... Oh, and did you say it was cold? Can't see that in your answer.

Comment: ahh i see.. that's why tho...

Answer (score -1):

I would use a couple of adaptors to connect the sensor to an airline and pressure test it that way - easy to check, no burnt fingers and plenty of room.

But if working in tight spaces is your thing there are other possibilities.